# JQGRID Search Modal window is not popping up

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid

I have using jquery ui tabs in that i am showing grid using jqGrid,the problem is when i click search/find option the search modal window  is not poping up,the page size is increasing and  it is showing on the top of the page, it is working fine in mozilla but not in IE 8.

And here is the script:

```
 jQuery("#lDR").jqGrid({ 
            altRows: true,
            altclass: 'alt',
            data: ldReportData, 
            datatype: "local",
            height: 'auto',
            colNames:[ 'PNumber',Number', 'SUpb', 'SP&I', 'FUpb', 'FP&I', 'UDelta'
                        ],

            colModel:[  {name:'pNum', index: 'pNum', width:100},
                        {name:'Nbr', index: 'Nbr', width:100},  
                        {name:'Amt', index: 'Amt', width:100}, 
                        {name:'PImt', index: 'PImt', width:100},
                        {name:'fAmt', index: 'fAmt', width:100}, 
                        {name:'fAmt', index: 'fIAmt', width:100},
                        {name:'deUpb', index: 'deUpb', width:100},
                        ],
            rowNum: 15,                         
            rowList:[50,100,150],
            pager:'#pagerLdr', 
            viewrecords: true, 
            sortname: 'poolNum',
            grouping : true,
            groupingView : {
                            groupField : ['pNum'],
                            groupColumnShow : [false],
                            groupText : ['<b>P Number - {0}</b>']
                            },
            caption: "Loan Details Table"
            }).navGrid("#pagerLdr",{edit:false,add:false,del:false});
```

Comment: Your code seems fine at first glance. You may need to post a larger code example, or even a jsfiddle demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @justin thank you for you quick reply and editing my post,  will try to get you ASAP, in btw, it is working fine in mozilla but problem in IE, can you suggest me some work around

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you , i have resolved the issue, by following this link and making position absolute

visit http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/jqgrid-4-1-1-search-dialog-issues/